# How to fix "Cannot get config because the route does not have a routeName" issue in react native navigation?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to use the react-navigation in react-native with redux as in the documentation but I get this error "Cannot get config because the route does not have a routeName". The code that I tried is given below

Also please explain to me , how to use "createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware"

```
import {
   createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import {
  reduxifyNavigator,
  createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware,
  createNavigationReducer,
} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import login from "./features/login/containers"
import settings from "./features/settings/containers"
import * as screenNames from "./navigation/screen_names";



const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    [screenNames.LOGIN]: login,
    [screenNames.SETTINGS]: settings
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: [screenNames.LOGIN]
  }
);

const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigator);
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,
});

// Note: createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware must be run before reduxifyNavigator
const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav,
);

const NavApp = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigator, "root");
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state: state.nav,
});
const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(NavApp);

const store = createStore(
  appReducer,
  applyMiddleware(middleware),
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: The error message is shown as this]

Answer (score 1):

You have initialRouteName defined as array.

```
    initialRouteName: [screenNames.LOGIN]
```

Unless it's key in object, it shouldn't be in braces.

```
    initialRouteName: screenNames.LOGIN
```

Should fix it.